# Write a program to solve the currency row problem using dynamic

Tags: c++

Write a program to solve Coin-row problem using dynamic programming (in c++)
Given the coin row: 5,1,2,10,6,2 
I wrote the code, but I get an error about the size. Why?
this is code

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int max(int a,int b){
   if(a>b)
       return a;
   else
       return b;
}
int main(){
   int coinrow[]={5,1,2,10,6,2};
   int size=sizeof(coinrow)/sizeof(coinrow[0]);
   //cout<<size;
   int i;
   int coins[size+1];
   for(i=0;i<size;i++){
       coins[i+1]=coinrow[i];
   }

   int F[size+1];
   F[0]=0;
   F[1]=coins[1];
   for(i=2;i<=size;i++){
       F[i]=max(coins[i]+F[i-2],F[i-1]);
   }
   cout<<F[size];
}
```

Comment: The size of an array has to be a compile time constant and known at compile time.. `int coins[size+1];` is a variable-length array (because `size` is not a compile time constant) and not valid C++. Some compilers support it with compiler extensions but its usage is limited. The memory is allocated on the stack and the stack size is limited. Larger arrays should be allocated on the heap. Use `std::vector` instead of VLAs. https://wandbox.org/permlink/iopCatWoYIVV4ntb

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @ThomasSablik: or `const`/`constexpr` as size might be known at compile time.

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error (active) E0028 expression must have a constant value Project6 H:\c++\Project6\Project6\Source.cpp 14 
This is the mistake I get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of an array has to be a compile time constant and known at compile time. `int coins[size+1];` is a variable-length array (because size is not a compile time constant) and not valid C++. Some compilers support it with compiler extensions but its usage is limited. The memory is allocated on the stack and the stack size is limited. Larger arrays should be allocated on the heap. Use `std::vector` (heap) or `const`/`constexpr` (stack) instead of VLAs. `const` doesn't guarantee a compile time constant.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int max(int a,int b){
   if(a>b)
       return a;
   else
       return b;
}
int main(){
   int coinrow[]={5,1,2,10,6,2};
   constexpr int size=sizeof(coinrow)/sizeof(coinrow[0]);
   //cout<<size;
   int i;
   int coins[size+1];
   for(i=0;i<size;i++){
       coins[i+1]=coinrow[i];
   }

   int F[size+1];
   F[0]=0;
   F[1]=coins[1];
   for(i=2;i<=size;i++){
       F[i]=max(coins[i]+F[i-2],F[i-1]);
   }
   cout<<F[size];
}
```

I prefer

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
   std::array coinrow = {5,1,2,10,6,2};
   constexpr auto size = coinrow.size();
   //cout<<size;

   std::array<int, size+1> coins;
   for(std::size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
       coins[i+1]=coinrow[i];
   }

   std::array<int, size+1> F;
   F[0]=0;
   F[1]=coins[1];
   for(std::size_t i=2;i<=size;i++){
       F[i]=std::max(coins[i]+F[i-2],F[i-1]);
   }
   std::cout<<F[size];
}
```

if the size is known at compile time and the stack can be used and

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(){
   std::vector coinrow = {5,1,2,10,6,2};
   auto size = coinrow.size();
   //cout<<size;

   std::vector<int> coins(size+1);
   for(std::size_t i=0;i<size;i++){
       coins[i+1]=coinrow[i];
   }

   std::vector<int> F(size+1);
   F[0]=0;
   F[1]=coins[1];
   for(std::size_t i=2;i<=size;i++){
       F[i]=std::max(coins[i]+F[i-2],F[i-1]);
   }
   std::cout<<F[size];
}
```

if the size not known at compile time or the heap has to be used.